# Watchkit Table Row Background Color programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, tablerow, watchkit

**Is there any way to set the color of a `WatchKit` `Table Row` programmatically?**

On the iPhone part of my app, I set each specific `Table Cell` with:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:[stringArrayColor objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

So basically trying to set the background color of each of these types of rows:

[image]

Comment: You could make a 1x1 pixel image with desired background color and set that image was the background.

Comment: Any way to do it similar to how I do it in a normal `TableView` by using built in `UIColor` instead of an `image`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of setting the background color of the row, you set the background color of the group.

Comment: Do you know where the doc is for that? I can't figure out how you'd reference that group background color in code? Thanks!

Comment: (Because the "New Year Celebration" background color would be different from the "February party" background color)

Comment: set an outlet to the group in your row controller,  then use the method described here in the WKInterfaceGroup documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceGroup_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceGroup/setBackgroundColor:

Answer (score 3):

Maybe after Watch OS 2.0 you can change color of row but for now you can only change color for group like this:

```
[row.rowGroup setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```